# Bayes Learning - MAP hypothesis

Tags: machine-learning, bayesian, bayes-theorem

Suppose I have a set of hypotheses $H = \{h_1, h_2\}$ mutual exclusive. For them $P(h_1) = 0.2$ and $P(h_2) = 0.3$ (prior distribution). Suppose we know also that

$$P(Y=0 | h_1) = 0.2$$ $$P(Y=0 | h_2) = 0.4$$

where $Y$ is an attribute (target) that can have two values $\{1,0\}$. Suppose finally that you observe the event $Y = 0$.

Which one is the MAP (Maximum a posteriori) hypothesis?

- MAP is $h_1$
- MAP is $h_2$
- there's no enough element to find MAP
- MAP $h_1$ = MAP $h_2$
- nobody of the possible answer above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is basic application of the [Bayes Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayes%27_theorem)

$$P(h_1|Y=0) = \frac{P(Y=0|h_1)P(h_1)}{P(Y=0)}=\frac{0.04}{P(Y=0)}$$
$$P(h_2|Y=0) = \frac{P(Y=0|h_2)P(h_2)}{P(Y=0)}=\frac{0.12}{P(Y=0)}$$

So the $h_2$ is the more probable hypothesis, as $P(Y=0)>0$